# Remove DIV element when IFRAME inside that DIV is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I want to remove an `iframediv` element when its `iframe` child element is clicked. I want to close Google Ads inside the `div` when the ad is clicked.
How can I do that?

This is my HTML document:

```
<div class="iframediv">
    <iframe src="otherdomin.com/page2"></iframe>
</div>
<div class="iframediv">
    <iframe src="otherdomin.com/page"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please show us what you tried ?

Comment: Clicks within the iframe will be registered on "otherdomain.com" and will not propagate to your page.

Comment: I want to close google ads contain div when we click on ad.

Comment: This isn't possible in the way you're trying now, and what you're doing sounds like attempting to abuse google ads, which I wouldn't suggest.

Comment: I have edited your question to put the problem statement at the start and improve some of the grammar. But please add the code you have tried with.

Answer (score 0):

Use JQuery's hide or remove method

```
<div class="iframediv" id="div1">
   <iframe src="otherdomin.com/page2" id="iframe1"></iframe>
</div>
<div class="iframediv" id="div2">
    <iframe src="otherdomin.com/page" id="iframe2"></iframe>
</div>

<script>
  $('#iframe1').click(function(){
     $('#div1').hide();
     //$('#div1').remove();
  });
</script>
```